# Ford Ranger low RPM misfire?

Tags: misfire, ranger

2000 Ford Ranger 3.0L 2WD.

I'm having a tough time figuring out if it's trans shudder or a misfire but leaning towards misfire at this point.  The rumbling really starts to happen during converter lockup but it also does it pulling out from a stop sign or red light until I accelerate to get the RPM's up it sort of smooths out.  I did notice it pecking cruising down the road especially on the highway I get a kick here and there which makes me think it's a misfire but it doesn't seem to do it under heavy load but only when I get cruising along.  I did change the trans fluid and filter the other day to try and rule out shudder but it's still doing it some I'm thinking it's a misfire now.  Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing it?  Could it be the beginning of wires breaking down or maybe dirty failing injectors?

Comment: Need to do some more troubleshooting to narrow things down. Have any parts been replaced? Any CEL codes? Have you checked the fuel pressure or done a compression test? I know the 4.0 Fords of this vintage have a fuel pressure test port, not sure about the 3.0. If the basic tune up items haven't been done in awhile, go ahead and do them to rule them out (plugs, wires, air/fuel filter). While the plugs are out, check their condition to see if the engine combustion is healthy. There are plenty of other things that can cause misfire but this would be good low-cost start.

Answer (score 0):

Those Rangers have notoriously poor automatic transmissions and rear differentials.  If you have no CEL's or OBD II codes, you'd have to consider the drive train first, especially if there is more than 100k miles on the odometer.

There are other possibilities, and I agree with masospagheti in the first comment.  I would add that the ignition coil pack, crankshaft & camshaft position sensors should also be suspect.  They could all be replaced with OE new for $150 from RockAuto.com.

Comment: thanks im gonna try the wires and plugs. if that doesnt fix it im gonna replace the coil.  i hope it isnt the TC or trans

Comment: I sure hope it's not the TC or tranny, either.  I had to have the tranny rebuilt on my Taurus 3.0 and it cost $2,200!